# CSS Sticky Footer - No Scrollbar when content div contains lots of text

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, footer, sticky

Im trying to build a sticky footer. I looked at ryanfaits' version and at this one http://matthiasschuetz.com/content/extras/css_template01.html

The last one works just fine but the problem is, that when I put in a lot of content into the content-div, the footer goes down and there is no scrollbar at the content-div. I tried at the content-div to set min-height, max-height, height and of course overflow=auto and overflow-y. Last one shows at least a disabled scrollbar but is still not working.

Any ideas? Im quite frustrated :(

Thanks alot!
Ron

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: I just worked with the code from these two websites.

Comment: Seeing as their code works, but not when you try to implement it, i can't help but feel that there must be inconsistencies between your implementation and the sources you quote, which is why i would love to see what you've tried so far. Maybe you're just missing a bottom margin on your content container?

Comment: the thing is that it is not implemented! these examples do not contain a content- oder main-div with a scrollbar. it just pushes the footer down (not sticky any more) or the rest of the main div is hidden behind the footer... thanks for your effort!

Comment: ah, you want a fixed footer then? try position: absolute, bottom: 0 then. it will make the footer ALWAYS on bottom (cept for ipad, iphones, android phones and tablet and other mobile devices)

Comment: I would like to have a sticky footer. But if I put in much content in the main-div then the footer is not sticky any more but will be pushed down. In this case I'd like to have a scrollbar in the main div. Seems weird that noboby has had this problem before...

Answer (score 2):

Ron
I had the same issue, so yes, your issues is valid with the sticky footer. You can try putting the following on the content container where your content starts 130px from the top.

```
#content-container {
margin-top:130px;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
```

I actually ended up making the whole wrapper div scroll by doing this:

```
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
overflow: auto;
```

}

```
#footer-container {
background-color:#263959;
color:#FFF;
height:110px;
min-width:1000px;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

If I use http://matthiasschuetz.com/content/extras/css_template01.html and expand the content it does not show me a scrollbar for the div. Maybe you should post your html/css online so people can take a look if this doesnt help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this to your CSS

```
html {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Second of all I didn't try your sticky footer, but I often use this one
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

This works very well.

Comment: This is nice, but then I have two scrollbars. One for the whole page and one smaller one for the content-div. I just need one for the content div. while scrolling thru the content I want the rest to stay where it is. BTW: I tried also ryanfaiits, but either the footer "eats up" the bottom of the content div - I want it to end right above the footer - or the same thing as with my first solution happens. Any further ideas how to solve my problem? thx again!